# jQuery file upload in codeigniter 3 shows 403 error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, jquery-file-upload

This is the jquery code for jquery file upload but it returns 403 error.

I'm using **Codeigniter version 3.1.4**

```
 $('.fileupload').fileupload({
            url: $(this).data("url"),
            dataType: 'json',
             async: true,
            done: function (e, data) {
                console.log('sry');
                if (data.result.status == true) {
                    console.log('helo');
                    $('#filename').html('');
                    $('#filename').val(data.result.file);


                }
                else {
                    $('.img_name').append('Try again!..');

                }
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                console.log('uploading_msg');
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                console.log(progress);
                $('.progress_1').html('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + progress + '" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: ' + progress + '%"><span class="sr-only">' + progress + '% Complete (success)</span> </div>');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show us all necessary code. We don't know what's in `$(this).data("url")`. You are probably calling wrong url or your codeigniter setup is bad.

Comment: Is CSRF token enabled ? check under `config.php`  for `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

Comment: @jagad89 thank you it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now working fine just changed `config.php` change `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`  to `$config['csrf_protection'] = false;`